# Подскажите, какие типы нужно проставить вместо any?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

```js
/*в этот масив я помещаю строчные элементы через запятую. Какой тип нужен вместо any?*/
const [selected, setSelected] = useState<any>([]);
/*сдесь хранится моя база в виде [{name: string, id: number}]. Какой тип нужен вместо any?*/
const [data, setData] = useState<any>(data);
/*а тут какой тип нужен для event который я передаю в эту функцию?*/
/*и для selected из верхнего state?*/
  const selectMultiple = (item: string, e: any) => {
    const arr = []
    arr.push(item)
    setSelected((selected: any) => [...selected, item])
    setHighlight(true)
  }
```

Comment: если в selected добавляются только строки, очевидно, его тип должен быть `string[]`. Тип для параметра `e`  можно указать только увидев, что в него передается. Так как он вообще не используется в функции - его можно просто убрать